# Import settings in Django

Tags: django

I have three settings files in my project:

**settings.py**

```
#common settings
```

**development.py**

```
#settings for development
from settings import *
SOME_VARIABLE = some_value1
```

**production.py**

```
#settings for production
from settings import *
SOME_VARIABLE = some_value2
```

I would like import **SOME_VARIABLE** in my django app.

- for *manage.py runserver --setttings=development* should import
  **SOME VARIABLE** from *development.py*
- for *manage.py runserver --setttings=production* should import **SOME
  VARIABLE** from *production.py*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your apps you should use settings like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
...
settings.SOME_VARIABLE
```

You should not worry where they come from.